# Where can I access man pages for "aptitude" if it is not on my system?

Tags: apt, aptitude

Sometimes I want to read man pages of programs I have not installed. Then I visit [ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/).

I entered `aptitude` in the search box but aptitude man pages are available only for lucid 10.04 LTS and precise 12.04 LTS. Why is that?

- Is it because Ubuntu prefers usage of `apt-get` over `aptitude`?
- Is there some other reason?
- Where else can I access man pages for specific for Ubuntu if I do not have the respective software installed?
- I know of http://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude but that is not specific for Ubuntu, correct?

Comment: Visit t[this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/aptitude.8.html)

Comment: For me the manpage is displayed for all releases (but linked to the presumably unchanges manpage from 12.04): http://manpages.ubuntu.com/aptitude.8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/#navigation and search for "aptitude-curses". I do not know why there is no results for plain "aptitude", but the man page for "aptitude-curses" seems to have same content.

Alternatively in terminal:

```
cd "$(xdg-user-dir DOWNLOAD)"
wget http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dman
chmod +x dman
# now the dman script is ready to use in the current directory

./dman aptitude-curses
# also possible to tell release name, if not the currently used is wanted
./dman --release bionic aptitude-curses
```

### UPDATE:

`dman` script is also included in a package called "bikeshed" in Universe repository that you could install by:

```
sudo apt install bikeshed
```

`dman aptitude` does not work by that version of `dman` (at least in Ubuntu 20.04), so you have to use `dman aptitude-curses`. That version gets data from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages.gz/ and works with Ubuntu distribution codenames, so you can use the `--release` option.

Alternatively you could install "debian-goodies" from the Main repository and use the version of `dman` given by it:

```
sudo apt install debian-goodies
```

`dman aptitude` works by the version of `dman` given by it. That version gets data from https://dyn.manpages.debian.org, though and does not work with Ubuntu distribution codenames, so you probably won't get the manual page of right version of a package.

**NOTE CONCERNING BOTH PACKAGES**: If you want to avoid installing depencencies, use `--no-install-recommends` option with `apt`, provided you don't need the (recommended) depencencies.

Comment: The debian-goodies has a lot of dependencies so it's better to download the dman script directly https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debian-goodies/-/raw/master/dman?ref_type=heads&inline=false

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Takkat pointed out, the man pages are just symlinks to precise manpages if you use the search bar. This is because aptitude hasn't undergo any changes in its functionality since precise in their manual page:

```
precise (12.04LTS) (admin): terminal-based package manager (terminal interface only)
0.6.6-1ubuntu1: amd64 i386
precise-updates (admin): terminal-based package manager (terminal interface only)
0.6.6-1ubuntu1.2: amd64 i386
quantal (12.10) (admin): terminal-based package manager
0.6.8.1-2ubuntu1: amd64 i386
raring (13.04) (admin): terminal-based package manager
0.6.8.1-2ubuntu2: amd64 i386
saucy (13.10) (admin): terminal-based package manager
0.6.8.2-1ubuntu2: amd64 i386
trusty (admin): terminal-based package manager
0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4: amd64 i386
```

All those versions doesn't include new stuff. If you see the changelog with, you will finde:

```
apt-get changelog aptitude | grep -n Documentation
23:    - Documentation:
99:  * Documentation:
1735:    - Documentation fixes from Kobayashi Noritatda (Closes: #389942).
2326:    - Documentation typo fixes. (Closes: #268916)
2512:    - Documentation fixes (Closes: #269102, #269100)
```

going to line 99:

```
aptitude (0.6.8.2-1) unstable; urgency=low

  * [...] some stuff I sip
  * Documentation:
    - Update for default value of APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant
      which is "true" since apt 0.8.15.3. (Closes: #685310)
    - Correctly reference APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant and
      SuggestsImportant which do not contain any hyphens.
      (Closes: #579071)
```

Through for Saucy the link should have changed it didn't so something happened in Ubuntu manpage (I'm using debian changelog) since also trusty isn't updated.

Normally Ubuntu doesn't change the manpage contents (except some typo) so I'm guessing some hiccup happened in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to simply install the man page for aptitude. They are part of the aptitude-common package. My Ubuntu 18.04 installation was configured to never install man pages, so after fixing that, I simply ran `apt install --reinstall aptitude-common` to get them.

Answer (score -1):

**aptitude** is a text-based interface to the Debian GNU/Linux package system.

It's a package management command line application that runs on all Debian systems including Ubuntu and the man page is just the link you have provided above and i think there is no more options included for specific Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, maythux! I was hoping to find _why_ the man pages are not available on the site I gave the link for. Otherwise, I mostly find what I want or it is called a bug like in my closed question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422024/bootchart-why-is-there-no-man-page) :(

Comment: Hi friend. I understand now but i can't answer whether it's a bug or not, i'm trying to search for. +1 for your nice question

Comment: BTW, in case we can't find maybe this link will be nice: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/aptitude-doc-en and people can use `jessie` or `wheezy` or whatever version they feel their Ubuntu comes from. What do you think?

Comment: I can't answer you technically but i'm getting this personal think that you are right